# What research has been done on Smart Grid software agents that both cooperate and compete?

Tags: power-engineering, math

**Background**

For my master's thesis in Applied Mathematics, I am looking for ways to apply game theory to problems related to the so-called "Smart Grid". I have found many papers in which all involved agents (that control energy management systems of, for instance, households) either all cooperate (see [1], [2], [3], and [4]) within the framework of cooperative game theory, or they all compete (see [5], [6], and [7]) within the framework of non-cooperative game theory, with one another.

However, I haven't seen any papers or books (yet) that deal with the setting in which individual agents can join either team A or team B (not both), and these teams compete with one another. So the agents within the teams cooperate with each other (in the context of smart grids, this can mean they share their surplus energy for free or a cheap price with their team members) while they coordinate together how they can harm all agents from the other team as much as possible.

I though such a setting could be plausible because a utility/retail company X might want their customers the cooperate with one another, while they might want them to compete with customers from another utility/retail company Y. So the companies X and Y compete *via* their customers.

**Questions**

1. Is the setting I described, in which the utility companies compete via their customers, realistic in a sense that it could be a future scenario?
2. Has any research been done in which game-theoretic methods are used to model the setting I described (in individuals within teams collaborate, but coordinate to compete as good as possible against other teams) ? Could you point me to any articles/papers or books?
3. Which research areas, besides cooperative and non-cooperative game theory, that are particularly relevant to the team-setting I described above?

**Sources**

[1] Nishantha Ekneligoda and Wayne W. Weaver, "Game-Theoretic Communication Structures in Microgrids", IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery, 2012

[2] Adriana Chris and Visa Koivunen, "Coalitional game based optimization of energy portfolio in smart grid communities", preprint, 2017

[3] Valentin Robu, Ramachandra Kota, Georgios Chalkiadakis, Alex Rogers, Nicholas R. Jennings, "Cooperative Virtual Power Plant Formation Using Scoring Rules", Proceedings of the Twenty-Sixth AAAI Conference on Artifical Intelligence, 2012

[4] Meritxell Vinyals, Valentin Robu, Alex Rogers and Nicholas R. Jennings "Prediction-of-Use Games: a Cooperative Game Theory Approach to Sustainable Energy Tariffs", Proceedings of the 13th International Conference on Autonomous Agents and Multiagent Systems, 2014

[5] S. Rasoul Etesami, Walid Saad, Narayan Mandayam, and H. Vincent Poor "Stochastic Games for Smart Grid Energy Management with Prospect Prosumers", preprint, 2017

[6] Sarvapali D. Ramchurn, Perukrishnen Vytelingum, Alex Rogers, and Nick Jennings "Agent-Based Control for Decentralised Demand Side Management in the Smart Grid", International Foundation for Autonomous Agents and Multiagent Systems, 2011

[7] Amir-Hamed Mohsenian-Rad, Vincent W. S. Wong, Juri Jatskevich, Robert Schober, and Alberto Leon-Garcia,"Autonomous Demand Side Management based on Game-Theoretic Energy Consumption Scheduling for the Future Smart Grid, IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid, 2010

Comment: That's a well written question an admirable list of references but your question isn't about electrical design so, I'm afraid, it will probably be closed as off topic. Regarding the problem itself, the problem is simplified to a certain extent in that the energy is all sloshing around the grid and a utility can't pipe my energy directly to you. With smart metering they will track the consumption per period - minute, 15 min or hour or whatever - and do the same with the suppliers. Any mismatch will result in the utility buying or selling to the grid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is all of too broad, seeks to find an external resource, and about economic algorithms research, not electrical engineering - each of which would individually disqualify it from eligibility here.

Comment: I do not think it is off-topic question. It is an electrical engineering question. It might be a research question, yes. But still smart grid operation and control is a main topic of current electrical engineering research and future.

Comment: No, it's entirely an economics question.  Electrical engineering is about as relevant to this as metallurgy is to central bank gold reserves - you have to understand certain basics of the thing you are arguing about the market for, but the market is a thing of its own, independent of the thing being marketed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the setting I described, in which the utility companies compete via their customers, realistic in a sense that it could be a future
>   scenario?

The current competition is choosing whether to stay on the grid with no way to generate power, to install power generation (wind/solar) and use the grid for a backup or to go off the grid entirely. There are a few problems associated with this.

The old pricing structure is based off of supplying power to the customer with power flowing one way, all costs are built into the rate the power company charges. This becomes a problem when a customer wants the power company to regulate their voltage and wants a fixed rate to sell power back to the power company, when the rates that the power company buys and sells power are not fixed and changes throughout the day. When energy is exchanged from one physical location to a cost is incurred. When there is too much energy the price can go negative.

Another problem is as more customers switch to solar and return power to the grid, it destabilizes the grid (which costs money to stabilize) it also changes the average pattern of consumption throughout the day, since energy generation is based of of mostly solar from consumers and changes with the weather.

> Has any research been done in which game-theoretic methods are used
>   to model the setting I described (in individuals within teams
>   collaborate, but coordinate to compete as good as possible against
>   other teams) ?  Could you point me to any articles/papers or books?

No, this question is off topic, we don't find resources or products for others. We do answer specific questions. This question also smacks of "doing someone else's homework for them". As part of your masters, you need to learn how to answer your questions with the resources available to you without leaning on other people.

That being said, I recommend scanning the IEEE spectrum for every article on the grid and also solar installations and smart grids. That will give you a good background on the state of affairs when it comes to consumers, engineering and grids.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the competition between the consumers is a realistic and an applicable option. I think it is better that the aggregators should be the agents rather than the consumers. This will make your assumptions more realistic as the aggregators are the real players in the smart grid market. [1] and [2] may help you.

Jumping to your third question, As a suggestion, I think cyber-physical attacks on smart grid is very good research area where game theory could be applied, in which the hacker/attacker is your opponent in the game. You may see [3] and [4] as example.

Ref.

[1] Nguyen, D.T., Negnevitsky, M. and De Groot, M., **Pool-based demand response exchange—concept and modeling**. IEEE Trans. Power Syst, 26(3), pp.1677-1685.  2011.

[2] Gkatzikis, L., Koutsopoulos, I. and Salonidis, T., **The role of aggregators in smart grid demand response markets**. IEEE Journal on Selected Areas in Communications, 31(7), pp.1247-1257. 2013.

[3] Farraj, A., Hammad, E., Al Daoud, A. and Kundur, D., **A game-theoretic analysis of cyber switching attacks and mitigation in smart grid systems**. IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid, 7(4), pp.1846-1855. 2016.

[4] Srikantha, P. and Kundur, D., **A DER attack-mitigation differential game for smart grid security analysis**. IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid, 7(3), pp.1476-1485. 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Google and Microsoft Scholar search engines are filled with similar thesis topics and papers.  On a practical matter Smart grid stability has been diagnosed with many proposals, but there are are many variables which make this question localized.  Power Authority contracts with major providers, lack multiple infrastructure from multiple sources, but may have 3rd party sub-carriers, supply demand of major sources like nuclear which must run 100% or else dump load, matching energy demand peaks with supply by availability and stability of supplier, not necessarily lowest theoretical loss path.

It is not a question that micro-grids will be important, but the main requirements are lowering cost of supply, increasing margin to overload and quality, stability and THD of source.

Considering dynamic power factor, dynamic motor surges power quality and cost models and details specs must be well defined before any solution can be entertained.